# Spring custom authenticator

Tags: spring, spring-security

i use spring 3.2, spring security 3.1 and a custom authenticator.

My security-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<sec:http use-expressions="true">

    <sec:form-login
        login-page="/login.html"
        default-target-url="/index.html"
        always-use-default-target='true'
        authentication-failure-url="/login-error.html"
    />
    <sec:logout
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/login.html"
    />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="any"/>

    <sec:http-basic />

</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider" id="daoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="authService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.test.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="authService"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.test.services.util.Encoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
```

i get this error:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in class path resource [config/security-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

My implementation class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws  UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
...
    }

}
```

i have also, but this code don't seem to be saw if we check my previous error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
...
  }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: What class is extended by `UserDetailsServiceImpl`?

Comment: she extends JdbcDaoImpl

Comment: Why do you have `@Service("userDetailsService")` on that class and, also, creating it in your xml configuration with `id="authService"`?

Comment: I believe you need to clean up your code a bit or explain in more details what you are trying to do. You have a `UserDetailsServiceImpl` but also you are defining `jdbc-user-service`. These look redundant to me.

Comment: i tried without  <bean class="com.test.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="authService"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>  
</bean>  
  
<bean class="com.test.services.util.Encoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>   and get the same error

Comment: Can you update what your configuration looks like now? I have the feeling you tried out some setups, some failed and what is now in the post is just a mix of different things.

Comment: Try something else: put back `UserDetailsServiceImpl` in xml, remove `@Service("userDetailsService")` from `UserDetailsServiceImpl`, and in xml add `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>` to `UserDetailsServiceImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

[JdbcDaoImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) is meant for the functionality of retrieving the user details from database using jdbc queries. A default database schema is assumed, with two tables "users" and "authorities" hence it requires a datasource or jdbc template ( this prerequisite comes from the fact that JdbcDaoImpl extends from [JdbcDaoSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html?is-external=true) which obviously requires these).
For implementing your own authentication provider take a look [here](http://technirman.blogspot.in/2014/01/spring-security-using-custom.html), [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/)

Comment: when i check this link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal it it's similar then what i done

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl implements UserDetailsService { ... }
```

Remove the `@Service` annotation, if you have a component-scan (which I assume) this bean will be picked up. As it extends `JdbcDaoImpl` which in turn extends `JdbcDaoSupport` a `DataSource` or `JdbcTemplate` is required. However this cannot be autowired by default.

```
<bean class="com.test.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="authService"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>
```

Also your bean definition lacks a reference to the datasource.

```
<bean class="com.test.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="authService"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Your `authService` isn't doing much as you also have a `<sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>` which constructs a default instance of Spring Security. Remove that element and have the change the `<sec:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />` to reference your `authService`.

```
<sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService" />
```

Basically the following should be enough

```
<sec:authentication-manager>   
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean class="com.test.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="authService"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.test.services.util.Encoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
```

You don't need the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` as that is done by Spring Security for you.